# Interaction between threads of the observer and the observable

Tags: java, observer-pattern

In an use case of parallel threading, I have one observer and multiple observables, and in the observer, there is a `getNotified(xxx)` method to receive the notifications from the observables.

My question is: Am I right or wrong when I make the following statement:

Since the `getNotified(xxx)` method should not block the main thread of the observer just for waiting for the notifications from the observables, so I would assume that there should be some other mechanisms, such as: When the observable wants to notify the observer, the observable's thread will start some kinds of inter-thread communication to the observer's thread, so the observer thread can pause what it is doing and process the received notification from the observable's thread?

My understanding about how observable pattern works without active checking/blocking for the notification is very limited. Thus any explanations or comments are very welcomed.

Comment: If it is possible, please also comment why you vote down the question, so I can understand and make better questions in the future.